# Generate a list of files/objects dynamically from within makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to do this:

From a directory, pick all the `C` (`.c`) files, generate `.o` and add it to
my final target executable. The `C` files can be added or removed at anytime, so when I 
run `make` for my target, the available `C` files from the directory has to be picked
to compile and link with my target.

So far, I have the following:

```
define test_tgt = 
DIR = full/path/to/dir
FILES = $(wildcard $(DIR)/*.c)
OBJS = <rule-to-convert-C-to-O>
endef

get_new_files: 
     $(eval $(test_tgt))

final-target: get_new_files 
      $(CC) <other-objs> $(OBJS)
```

Somehow this doesn't seem to work. I see a lot of similar examples, but not sure what
is wrong here. If this approach is not correct, can anyone suggest a better way to 
accomplish this.

TIA.

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to program a check that `make` does by itself.
Just list `$(OBJS)` as dependencies of `final-target`.

Something like this should work under GNU make:

```
DIR = full/path/to/dir
FILES = $(wildcard $(DIR)/*.c)
OBJS = $(subst .c,.o,$(FILES))

final-target: $(OBJS)
    $(LD) -o $@ $+  # or similar
```

Full documentation is here: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html

Comment: Substitution references are your friend: `OBJS = $(FILES:.c=.o)`.

Comment: @reinierpost, thanks, I will try this as well. I found a solution on other SO thread, which used, `target: <generate-fragment> > $@`, and then `-include target`

Comment: Huh? You can only `-include target` if it is a Makefile.